# Must $G$ be a transitive group to ensure bijection between orbits?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

In Godsil and Royle's *Algebraic Graph Theory*, they prove this lemma about orbits of a transitive group action:

> Let $G$ be a transitive group acting on a set $V$, and let $x$ be a fixed element of $V$. Then there is a bijection between orbits of $G$ on $V\times V$ and orbits of $G_x$ on $V$.

**Where in the following proof is the assumption that $G$ is transitive used?**

*Proof:* Let $S$ be an orbit of $G$ on $V\times V$, and define the set $Y_S:=\{y\in V: (x,y)\in S\}$. Let $y$ be an element of $Y_S$. To show that $Y_S$ is an orbit of $G_x$ on $V$, we show that $Y_S = y^{G_x}$. For any $z\in Y_S$, by construction we know that $(x,z),(x,y)\in S$, which implies that there is some $g\in G$ such that $(x,y)^g = (x,z)$, implying that $g\in G_x$ and $z=y^g$, hence $z\in y^{G_x}$. Conversely, consider some $z\in y^{G_x}$. Then there is some $g\in G_x$ such that $y^g = z$, hence $(x,y)^g = (x,z)$, implying that $z\in Y_S$. Hence, $Y_S$ is indeed an orbit of $G_x$ on $V$.

Because these $Y_S$ partition $V$ completely for all orbits $S$, all orbits of $G_x$ must be of this form and the result is shown. $\quad\square$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $G$ is **not** transitive on $V$. Let $x$ and $x'$ be in different
orbits of $G$ on $V$. Then no orbit on $V\times V$ containing an element
of the form $(x',y)$ is accounted for in your proposed "bijection".

The crucial part of the proof is that each orbit of $G$ on $V\times V$
contains an element $(x,y)$ where $x$ is your given element of $V$.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. Thank you! And do you mean different orbits of $G_x$ on $V$?

Comment: @SantanaAfton I mean what I say!

Comment: I get it now! Thanks.